# How to set build version info via pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my build job on Jenkins via pipeline, I need show build description in build history list. how to set it in pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this support article](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/220860347-How-to-set-build-name-in-Pipeline-job-), you can update the display name of a given build by running `currentBuild.displayName = "7.6.2"` (or whatever your version is) within a script block.

So with the use of the version number plugin, you can do something like this:

```
BUILD_VERSION_GENERATED = VersionNumber(
        versionNumberString: '7.6.2.${BUILDS_ALL_TIME, X}',
        projectStartDate:    '1970-01-01',
        skipFailedBuilds:    true)
currentBuild.displayName = BUILD_VERSION_GENERATED
```

Wrap that in a `script {}` block in the `steps` section of a stage if you're using declarative pipeline and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Execute the script Console (`$JENKINS_URL/script`):

```
def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("folderName/my-pipeline-job")
job.nextBuildNumber = 10
job.save()
```

Replace `folderName/my-pipeline-job` with your folder/job name with the desired next build number.

Comment: def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("$Testbuild")
job.nextBuildNumber = 10
job.save(),   how to add into pipeline script?

Comment: The script console isn't the same as the Jenkinsfile declarative pipeline config. They're asking how to set the build number per build in that config (presumably because it's being generated in one of the preliminary steps).